# Configure a code snippet to auto-expand? (Extensions are fine)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is it possible to create a code snippet that expands automatically the instant I type the last letter of its "shortcut" (without requiring me to press Tab twice, etc.), and if so, how do I do that? Right now I'm getting by by having configured a more convenient keystroke for `Edit.InvokeSnippetFromShortcut`, but it's still a keystroke I don't feel the need for (for a small set of snippets).

(I have no problem installing an extension if necessary to make snippets better, including something I'd have to buy.)

Comment: what a pain if the snippets expand automatically, imagine each time you write "prop" or "if" or "try", etc. the full snippet will expand, even if you didn't want the snippet at this time.

Comment: @SteveB: As I said above, *"...for a small set of snippets..."*. Certainly wouldn't use it for `if`, `try`, etc.

Comment: I missed that part of the sentence. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is probably a Macro - [MSDN Info on Macro Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0003t62%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

You can either create a macro which types the snippet and press tab twice, or create the snippet code through it.

Comment: Thanks. That page says that I can invoke macros in several ways (keyboard shortcut, via the Macro Explorer, etc.), but none of those ways is when I type the last character of a sequence in the text editor.